# Open view controller in Landscape mode initially in ios sdk

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

i am using ios sdk 5

i am pushing a view controller from parent view controller like this

```
DetailsViewController *detailController = [[DetailsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailsViewController" bundle:nil] ;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft animated:YES];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailController animated:YES];
```

becuase i want to open my new controller in Landscape mode.My parent view controller is in potrait mode so i have set to

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}
```

and in my child view controller i have set it to

```
   - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
    {
         return interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
    }
```

But still when my child view controller opens it rotates to landscape mode but the inner views like scrollview and its subviews remains in potrait mode. i have read a lot of similar questions and tried them but none of them are working for me .Please point me to right direction as to how to rotate all the view in viewcontroller

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the method,

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
     return interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
}
```

by,

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
     return  UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(interfaceOrientation);
}
```

Comment: i tried it K.D but its still not rotating the scrollview and its inner views.

Comment: if u want your view to i.e. Landscape than return  UIInterfaceOrientationILandscape(interfaceOrientation);                , and set only landscape orietation in .plist file and remove the other orientation from it.